# How to execute dos command on separate thread in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, node.js, npm, dos

I am using

```
var version = shell.exec('D:\\prompt.bat', {silent:false}).output;
```

Shelljs module of npm to run .bat file

this .bat file opens the iexplore.exe and internet explorer opens up

**BUT**
 The problem is it runs on single thread so untill and unless IE is not bieng closed my server is waitng and not processing any further request,

so anyone can please suggest me how to run DOS command on separate thread so that it does not affect my server.

thanks in advance. :)

Comment: If you run out of ideas, I'd try it with cmd.exe, which can certainly run bat files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use something different like [*child_process*](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) or [*exec*](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec) to create async process, but node.js is still not going to exit until the child process is finished or timed out. Though it will continue execution.

Example ([source](https://www.npmjs.org/package/exec)):

```
var exec = require('exec');

exec(['D:\\prompt.bat'], function(err, out, code) {
  if (err instanceof Error)
    throw err;
  process.stderr.write(err);
  process.stdout.write(out);
  process.exit(code);
});
```

---

Alternative and easier method: you can try running async CMD code, that is solving issue not in Node.js but in  script.

For instance change the line to:

```
var version = shell.exec('start D:\\prompt.bat', {silent:false}).output;
```

Or you could add command `start` inside of a `prompt.bat`.

Comment: mannnnnnnnnn............... i wasted my whole day in this, i tried this earlier but it was not working , i don't know how suddenly this started working :) :) thanks alot.

Comment: but in place of this exec(['D:\\prompt.bat'], function(err, out, code) {...} i want to execute 'C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe' how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

i found answer for my second question in comment by myself:

in place of c:\... something use c:/ that is it. :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.